# Woocommerce Custom Payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

We are planning to use a payment gateway that does not have a standard woocommerce plugin. Before we did that, I wanted to know is it even possible to do this?

Basically we will have the API from the Payment gateway (in PHP) and will need to make calls to get a payment processed and send a success / failure response to Woocommerce -

Is this even possible? If so, any leads / documentation on how to do this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below tutorials to create plugin for payment gateway you wish:

https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-woocommerce-payment-extension/
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/payment-gateway-api/